# I'm trying to make a modal open but only if the user clicks the check box to agree to the ToS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

After the user agrees to the TOS, I'd like a modal to pop up stating that the user is leaving the site for another site. For some reason, I can't seem to get the actual check box to appear though. I've been tinkering with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

This is where I've been having the trouble. It looks like stack overflow says that I'm posting too much code and that I should state more about the issue. I'm not quite sure how else to say it but basically, I'd like the user to check the checkbox for the ToS and only if the box is checked, will a modal open.

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<form action="https://google.com" method="GET" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">     
<p>You are leaving this site and going to a third-party site</p>
<input type="submit" value="Agree and Continue">
</form>
      <p>Some other text...</p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  <input type="checkbox" required><label for="scales">
<b> I Agree to the  <a href="example.com/TOS">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="https://example.com/PP">Privacy Policy</a></b>

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is that supposed to be the actual code? You can not just use plain HTML again _inside_ of a `script` element.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<form action="https://google.com" method="GET" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">     
<p>You are leaving this site and going to a third-party site</p>
<input type="submit" value="Agree and Continue">
</form>
      <p>Some other text...</p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<input type="checkbox" required><label for="scales">

<b> I Agree to the  <a href="example.com/TOS">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="https://example.com/PP">Privacy Policy</a></b>


<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I copied your code but the modal won't open regardless of whether the box is checked or not. I see it works here though.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button if the checkbox isn't checked. Try something like this:

```js
$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
  $('.proceed').toggleClass("checked");
});
```

```css
.proceed{
  display:none;
}
.checked{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"> I Agree to the <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.
<br>
<button id="myBtn" class="proceed">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's awesome code. I realize that I'm a bit out of my league here. I'm having a heck of a time combining the two codes so that the button only appears once the check mark is ticket and then when the button is clicked, it opens the modal.